# "find", "each" method throw type mismatch error

Tags: scala.js

I am trying to iterate over options using `val x = $(selectState).find("option").each((y: Element) => y)`. However Compilation throw following error.

```
type mismatch;
 found   : org.scalajs.dom.Element => org.scalajs.dom.Element
    (which expands to)  org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element => org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element
 required: scala.scalajs.js.|[scala.scalajs.js.ThisFunction0[org.scalajs.dom.Element,Any],scala.scalajs.js.ThisFunction1[org.scalajs.dom.Element,Int,Any]]
    (which expands to)  scala.scalajs.js.|[scala.scalajs.js.ThisFunction0[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element,Any],scala.scalajs.js.ThisFunction1[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element,Int,Any]]
```

I was referring to stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483226/call-jquery-each-method-from-scala-js).

Comment: Which jQuery facade are you using and which version?

Comment: Based on the issue you raised in jquery-facade, I assume you're using that.  It's odd -- I don't see offhand why that call to `each` isn't compiling.  I'll try to look into that today, and see if I can figure out what's up.  (Might be that the use of `|` is preventing the Scala function from implicitly converting to a JavaScript one, in which case I'll need to rewrite the facade for `each`.)

Comment: I am using jquery-facade version 1.0-RC2

Comment: Working on it now -- I've repro'ed the problem, and am confirming the cause...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, answering this formally: yep, that was a bug in jquery-facade. Thanks for pointing it out!

The issue, as I suspected, was that the `|` type operator interferes with the compiler's ability to automatically cast Scala functions to JavaScript ones. So it wasn't understanding that `(y: Element) => y` (a Scala function) could be turned into a JavaScript js.Function0[Element, Any].

So I've split `each` into two separate overloads, one for each version, and that appears to work as desired. Please update to jquery-facade 1.0-RC3, and I think it should work for you.